# Extract keywords from referrer URL

Tags: php, referrer

It seems Google's URLs are structured differently these days.  So it is harder to extract the referring keyword from them.  Here is an example:

> `http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+post+output+46&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#pq=jquery+post+output+46&hl=en&cp=30&gs_id=1v&xhr=t&q=jquery+post+output+php+not+running&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-a&hs=8N5&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=jquery+post+output+php+not+run&aq=0w&aqi=q-w1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=bdeb326aa44b07c5&biw=1280&bih=875`

The search I performed was actually "*jquery post output php not running*", so the first 'q=' does not contain the full search.  The second one does.  I'd like to write a script that always extracts the last 'q=', but I'm not sure if Google's URL's always have the full search last. Anyone had any experience with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url), [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str), and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode), where `$str` is the refer string:

```
$fragment = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
parse_str($fragment, $arr);

$query = urldecode($arr['q']); // jquery post output php not running
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm struggling to figure out how this works.  When I print_r $arr it looks as if there is only one 'q' variable, even though in the URL there is clearly 2.  Does your code somehow combine the 'q' parts?  An explanation will help me learn more.

Comment: @LucasScholten:  The second parameter in `parse_url` extracts only what's after the hash mark (`#`) in the URL, therefore there will only be one "q".

Comment: in that case I have added this at the top of the script

`if(strpos($_POST['referrer'],"#")>0)
{
 $fragment = parse_url($_POST['referrer'], PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
}
else
{
 $fragment = parse_url($_POST['referrer'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
}`

Since not all google urls are fragmented